# Evaluating $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\cos(\sin x)-(1+x^2)^{\frac{-1}{2}}}{x^4}$

Tags: calculus, limits

$$L=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\cos(\sin x)-(1+x^2)^{\frac{-1}{2}}}{x^4}$$
To Evaluate the limit I used few terms of taylor series:

$\cos(\sin x)=1-\frac{\sin^2 x}2+\cdots$

$(1+x^2)^{\frac{-1}2}=1-\frac12x^2+\cdots$

$$L=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1-\frac{\sin^2 x}{2}-1+\frac{x^2}{2}}{x^4}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{x^2-\sin^2 x}{2x^4}$$

$\sin^2 x=(x-\frac{x^3}{6}+O(x^4))^2=x^2-\frac{x^4}{3}+O(x^5)$

So we have:$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x^2-x^2+\frac{x^4}{3}}{2x^4}=\frac{1}{6}$$

But the right answer is $\frac{-1}6$. Why my final answer is wrong?

Comment: you should expand $(1+x^2)^{\frac{-1}{2}}$ to atleast $x^4$

Comment: @AdityaDwivedi Why?and then I should write more terms for other functions too?

Comment: it is important as the denominator contains $x^4$ so you should expand all the functions to that terms

Comment: @AdityaDwivedi Oh, I see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a standard application of Taylor series, hence Community Wiki.

We have $\cos x=1-\frac12x^2+\frac1{24}x^4-\cdots$ and $\sin x=x-\frac16x^3+\cdots$, so
$$
\begin{aligned}
\cos (\sin x)&=1-\frac12\sin^2 x+\frac1{24}\sin^4x+\cdots\\
&=1-(\frac12x^2-\frac16x^4+O(x^6))+\frac1{24}(x^4+O(x^6))\\
&=1-\frac12x^2+\frac5{24}x^4+O(x^6).
\end{aligned}
$$
Similarly (use the binomial series) the Taylor series of
$$
1/\sqrt{1+x^2}=1-\frac12x^2+\frac9{24}x^4+O(x^6).
$$
Therefore
$$
\cos(\sin x)-\frac1{\sqrt{1+x^2}}=-\frac16x^4+
O(x^6).
$$
From this it follows immediately that the limit is equal to $-1/6$.

Everywhere $O(x^6)$ stands for terms of degree six or higher.

---

The problem with the attempt in the original post is that in the first step some terms of degree four were neglected. In the end we cancel a factor of $x^4$, so this was a mistake.

Comment: Thanks. I am new at using taylor series to evaluate limits. So, how many of first terms of the series should be written to get the right answer? I used very few terms and got wrong. In this case as @AdityaDwivedi pointed out we should write it until $x^4$. but how many terms needed in general?

Comment: @soheil That depends. You see that in the end we divide by $x^4$. For that to make sense there must not be any unknown $x^4$. If, instead, we had a limit like
$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\cos(\sin x)-1/\sqrt{1+x^2}+x^4/6}{x^6},$$
then at the end we would be cancelling a factor $x^6$. In that case it would be necessary for the series to be accurate up to terms of degree six.

Comment: Very good explanation I completely understand now.

Answer (score -1):

Write  $\cos(\sin x)-(1+x^2)^{1/2}$ as $\cos(\sin x)-\cos x+\cos x-(1+x^2)^{1/2}$

Then,
$$\cos(\sin x)-\cos x=2\sin\dfrac{x-\sin x}2\sin\dfrac{x+\sin x}2$$

Now use L'Hospital's or  [Are all limits solvable without L'Hôpital Rule or Series Expansion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/387333/are-all-limits-solvable-without-lh%c3%b4pital-rule-or-series-expansion) to find $$\lim_{x\to0}\dfrac{x-\sin x}{x^3}=\dfrac16$$  so that $$\lim_{x\to0}\dfrac{\cos(\sin x)-\cos x}{x^4}=\dfrac24\lim_{x\to0}\dfrac{\sin\dfrac{x-\sin x}2}{\dfrac{x-\sin x}2}\lim_{x\to0}\dfrac{\sin\dfrac{x+\sin x}2}{\dfrac{x+\sin x}2}\lim_{x\to0}\dfrac{x-\sin x}{x^3}\lim_{x\to0}\dfrac{x+\sin x}x$$

Finally $$\cos x-(1+x^2)^{-1/2}$$

$$=1-\dfrac{x^2}{2!}+\dfrac{x^4}{4!}-\cdots-\left(1-\dfrac{x^2}2+x^4\cdot\dfrac{\left(-\dfrac12\right)\left(-\dfrac12-1\right)}{2!}+\cdots\right)$$

$$=x^4\cdot\left(\dfrac1{4!}-\dfrac38\right)+\text{terms containing higher exponents of }x$$

Comment: Still wrong. The correct answer is $-1/6$. I had Mathematica plot the function.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen, Rectified $$\dfrac16-\dfrac13$$

Comment: Yeah, I was wondering whether you simply forgot about the difference between $\cos x$ and $\cos(\sin x)$ at the end. Anyway, as we need to use the Taylor series anyway, I don't see the point of the excursion via trig identities..

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen, No, I didn't.  In many cases one should admit, this approximation works. But this is really tricky nice problem